# How to get Date in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa

I have an issue and I don't know how to solve it. I have a MySQL database where there is a table that have a field TIMESTAMP filled with a value like `2014-06-18 10:00:00` made of date plus time.

I would like to retrieve the row trough JPA passing only the date for instance `18/06/2014` and not the time. I have tried to do that

```
...
    .setParameter("date", getDate(date, "", ""), TemporalType.DATE)
...
```

where `getDate()` is the following method but I am not able to get that row. Infact if I made the query without the parameter of the date everything works well. Then it means that there is a problem in comparing the date. How can I solve it?

```
public Date getDate(String date, String hours, String minutes) //Spostare questa funzione
{    
    Date dateToStore = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    try
    {
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(hours) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(minutes))
        {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
            dateToStore = sdf.parse(date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes);
        }
        else
        {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            dateToStore = sdf.parse(date);
        }

    } 
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        //Errore nel parsing della data
}

    return dateToStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

```
public static Date stringToDate(String stringDate, String format) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = sdf.parse(stringDate);
    return date;
}
```

And then call it in the following way:

```
Date formattedDate = stringToDate(originalDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
```

This will give you a Date object from the String you read from DB.

If you want to obtain an String with the date from DB instead, you can use the following:

```
public static String convertDate(String stringDate, String oldFormat, String newFormat) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
    Date date = sdf.parse(stringDate);
    sdf.applyPattern(newFormat);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

And then:

```
String formattedDate = convertDate(originalDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Which error are you getting now? I'd also like to know if you need a Date object or a String with a formatted date

Comment: i don't get any error...simply I don't get the row I want because surely the date inserted is not well compared to that in the db

Comment: I need to know what are you recovering from de DB

Comment: This is the date I got when I exceute stringToDate function: Wed Jun 18 00:00:00 CEST 2014 passing stringToDate("18/06/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: This is the field I' trying to recover from the database @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date departure_date;

Comment: This is the field stored in mysql database field TIMESTAMP 2014-06-18 10:00:00

Comment: A Date object allways has a date + time data. If you only want to show the date, you must format it to an String with SimpleDateFormat for example. Try using the second method I posted, it'll give you an String with the wanted format.

Comment: No I don't think it is the problem...if you add when you call setParameter the field TemporalType the jpa know that it has to compare only date and not the time.

Comment: I repeat what I would like to get. I have stored in the db the date  2014-06-18 10:00:00. When I ask for the date 2014-06-18, I have to get that row despite the time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55766/discussion-between-genzotto-and-eng-mazzy).

Comment: I have finally solved the problem...I had to change my point of view. When I made the query. I used the BETWEEN CLAUSE from 00:00 to 23:59

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you have written in the date parsing?

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
dateToStore = sdf.parse(date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes);
```

What are the parameters of the method?

```
getDate(date, "", ""),
```

So, you get this:

```
dateToStore = sdf.parse(date + " :");
```

Which of course won't construct a proper date. If you reverse that line of thinking, you will find that you wan to call `getDate(date, "00", "00")`.

Comment: If you look at the method aboce I have modified it but It still doesn't work

Comment: Ah, indeed. You might want to print the exception's stack trace instead of ignoring it, and amending your question with the output, that would help.